# create UIImage from UIWebView then add to pdf

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview, uiimage

I am creating a pdf in Objective C, I have created the pdf and everything works fine. I have a `NSString` that contains `HTML` code I would like to create a `UIWebView` from this, then create a `UIImage` from the `UIWebView` and finally add the `UIImage` to the pdf I am creating.

This is what I have done so far:

```
// inside create pdf method.
    UIWebView *tempDescWV = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    NSString *updatedDescHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<script type=""text/javascript"" src=""./myscript.js"">%@</script>", descriptionHTML];
    [tempDescWV loadHTMLString:updatedDescHTML baseURL:nil];



// pdf creation code all goes here.
// now I try to load my UIImage onto the pdf.

UIImage *tempImage = [self imageFromWebView:tempDescWV];
        [tempImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(65.0, 55.0, 210.0, 550.0)];
```

The only thing that shows is a white block.. if I preview the `UIWebView` its completely blank, however when I debug the string I am using for `loadHTMLString` I can see the `HTML` in there.

this is `imageFromWebView` method, this seems to work its just the html is now being loaded into the `UIWebView`.

```
- (UIImage *) imageFromWebView:(UIWebView *)view
{
    // tempframe to reset view size after image was created
    CGRect tmpFrame         = view.frame;

    // set new Frame
    CGRect aFrame               = view.frame;
    aFrame.size.height  = [view sizeThatFits:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size].height;
    view.frame              = aFrame;

    // do image magic
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([view sizeThatFits:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size]);

    CGContextRef resizedContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [view.layer renderInContext:resizedContext];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // reset Frame of view to origin
    view.frame = tmpFrame;
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIWebView` loads asynchronously, so it won't have rendered anything by the time you are trying to take an image of it.  You should set yourself as the webview's delegate and then create your image in the `webViewDidFinishLoad:` callback.

Answer (score 0):

first its right what dan wrotes. for taking the shot use the follwing:

```
- (UIImage *)takeScreenshotFromView:(UIView*)theView { //pass here your webview
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(theView.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    [theView drawViewHierarchyInRect:theView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: I have tried using this, but on the line where your using drawViewHierarchyInRect: the application is crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code=1...